# PHPUnit_Util_Type::export() in version 4.0

Tags: php, magento, phpunit

Can you guys help me locate what happened to `export` function in this:

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.7/PHPUnit/Util/Type.php

That function is still called by `EcomDev_PHPUnit` code (Magento tests).

It's lurking somewhere else but  I can't seem to find what happened to the `export` function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the commit:

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/commit/b8b3e1fdc0312938d8ce2d7ff5958d52c865d780

All output function were moved to `SebastianBergmann\Exporter\Exporter`.

`PHPUnit_Util_Type::export($key)`=> `$this->exporter->export($key)`,
`PHPUnit_Util_Type::shortenedExport($value)` => `$this->exporter->shortenedExport($value)`

The only problem now is to invoke `exporter` within scope.